# Django 2.2.6 (Python 3.6) + Apache + Ubuntu 18.04.3 error

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I made a django project and I tried deploying it with apache and wsgi, however I'm getting the following error in error.log:

```
Current thread  (most recent call first):
[Wed Dec 04 17:14:02. 2019] [core:notice] [pid :tid ] AH00051: child pid 27347 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I'm using **python 3.6.9**, I've installed every necessary library using pip3 and I've installed ibapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 using apt.

This is my **mysite.conf** in /sites-available

```
 WSGIPythonHome /var/www/projectenv/lib/python3.6
 WSGIPythonPath /var/www/projectenv/bin/python3
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project/project/project/wsgi.py


<VirtualHost *:80>
 # adjust the following line to match your Python path

 <directory /var/www/project/site>
  <Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
  </Files>
 </directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Django 2.2.6 is only compatible with python 3, so I'm not sure what to do. I'm not married to the idea of using apache, so if you have any recommendations for other webservers, that will serve as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `PYTHON_PATH` is correct?

Comment: How can I be sure? Where should I put the correct PYTHON_PATH? I'm sorry it's the first time I've run into this issue.